# Prolog: quicksort using last element as pivot (infinite loop)

Tags: prolog, quicksort

I'm trying to implement Quicksort in Prolog using the last element as pivot but somehow my predicate gets into an infinite loop. I'm using an accumulator to determine the part sorted so far (which in the end should be equal to the sorted list S that it should be looking for).

```
quicksort([], S, S).
quicksort(L, S, A ) :-
    lastElement(L, P), /*last element P as pivot*/
    split(L, P, Greater, Smaller), /* splits L into set Greater (than) and Smaller (than) by pivot P */
    quicksort(Greater, Greater_S, A), /* require Greater to be sorted as well, calling this Greater_S */
    quicksort(Smaller, S, [P|Greater_S]). /* same for Smaller, but accumulator should already have P and Greater_S sorted -> [P|Greater_S] as accumulator */

quicksort(L, S) :-
    quicksort(L, S, []).
```

Somehow in `quicksort(G, G_S, A)`, the list `G_S` seems to iteratively increase in size with the same element, i.e. `[X, X, X, X, ...]`.

What am I doing wrong?

If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Definitions of the predicates `split/4` and `lastElement/2`:

```
lastElement([X], X). 
lastElement([_|T], X) :- lastElement(T, X). 

split([], _, [], []).
split([H|T], P, G, K) :-
    H > P,
    G = [H|T_],
    split(T, P, T_, K).
split([H|T], P, G, K) :-
    H =< P,
    K = [H|T_],
    split(T, P, G, T_).
```

Comment: Rename one of your S variables.

Comment: You remember that the last element in the first argument to `deel/4` has the pivot as the last element, right? Anyway, what is this accumulator for, exactly?

Comment: Add the definitions for `lastElement/2` and `deel/4`!

Comment: @Boris Yes, well I followed the way in which Wikipedia wrote an example of Quicksort in Prolog using an accumulator (but using the first element as pivot) to keep track of the part that's ordered so far (if I'm not misunderstanding), so in the end it would add up to S. Therefore I figured quicksort(Smaller, S, [P|Greater_S]) should be valid since S is Smaller sorted combined with what's already sorted: [P|Greater_S] (calculated in the previous call to quicksort).

Comment: @Skyfe Sorry about the question, but why are you doing a) quicksort and b) using the last element? Both are poor choices, mainly because of how lists are represented in Prolog (basically, `cons` pairs).

Comment: @vmg My bad, updated the post. I innitially changed some variable names from Dutch to English but overlooked the conflict (in my real code with Dutch variable and function names they were already named different though).

Comment: @Boris I have to do this for a course Artificial Intelligence which I'm currently following, both are restrictions of the exercise.

Comment: @Skyfe And btw, I looked at the wikipedia Prolog quicksort [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Quicksort); this **does not** use an accumulator; it uses normal tail recursion and difference lists.

Comment: @Boris Hmm it seems the english version has different example code, I've got mine from: [here](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Voorbeeld_in_Prolog).

Comment: @Skyfe Uff, that code is terrible :-( the version on the English page that I linked is definitely easier to start from, at least. Suggestion: instead of taking the first element, just find a way to **remove** the last element from the list and then reuse the existing code. Taking the last element from a list is as easy as `append(Front, [Last], List)`. Don't use append for anything else though, you don't have to -- see how the English wikipedia version uses difference lists instead.

Comment: PS: some clever ass decided to use a DCG to define the `quicksort//1` instead of `quicksort/3`; you might need to figure out how to translate the DCG to a normal predicate or use `phrase` to evaluate the DCG.

Comment: @Boris Ah alright thanks I'll have a look into that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer below; however **please** compare the original version to the "last element as pivot" version and you will see that "last element as pivot" is just silly. Is it possible that there is a gotcha somewhere in the problem statement that we are both missing?

---

It seems to me that your life will be easier if you used a simpler Quicksort implementation as a starting point. From the [Prolog wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Quicksort)

```
partition([], _, [], []).
partition([X|Xs], Pivot, Smalls, Bigs) :-
    (   X @< Pivot ->
        Smalls = [X|Rest],
        partition(Xs, Pivot, Rest, Bigs)
    ;   Bigs = [X|Rest],
        partition(Xs, Pivot, Smalls, Rest)
    ).

quicksort([])     --> [].
quicksort([X|Xs]) -->
    { partition(Xs, X, Smaller, Bigger) },
    quicksort(Smaller), [X], quicksort(Bigger).
```

You will have to use `phrase`:

```
quicksort(List, Sorted) :- phrase(quicksort(List), Sorted).
```

So now it sorts:

```
?- quicksort([c,b,a,b], S).
S = [a, b, b, c].
```

The only thing you would have to change is to take the last element instead of the first, probably in the second clause of `quicksort//1`, like this:

```
quicksort([X|Xs]) -->
    {   append(Front, [Pivot], [X|Xs]),
        partition(Front, Pivot, Smaller, Bigger)
    },
    quicksort(Smaller), [Pivot], quicksort(Bigger).
```

This use of `append/3` leaves behind a choice point; you could write your own `list_front_last/3` if you want, or use

```
once( append(...) )
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

you can change your implementation of `lastElement` just a bit:

```
list_front_last([], Last, [], Last).
list_front_last([X|Xs], X0, [X0|Front], Last) :-
    list_front_last(Xs, X, Front, Last).
```

You have already unpacked the first value in the head of `quicksort//1`:

```
quicksort([X|Xs]) --> ...
```

so you can directly use

```
list_front_last(Xs, X, Front, Pivot)
```

instead of the call to `append/3`.

Comment: @Skyfe Thank you for accepting this answer; please make sure to read the waring that I added to the top of my answer!